# Windows 2012 & Remote Desktop Users group

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

On Windows Server 2012, it seems that, by default, only users in the Administrators group are permitted to log on remotely to a Windows 2012 server.

How can I use PowerShell to allow users who are in the "Remote Desktop Users" group (but not in the Administrators group) to log in remotely?

Comment: They are in the "Remote Desktop Users" group on the server and still cannot remote in?

Comment: Yes, they are in the Remote Desktop Users group and they still cannot log in. The machine I was running on happens to be a domain controller, could it have different rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...a DC will have different rules (even on a 2008/2003.

You'll first need to set this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785165%28WS.10%29.aspx

Then:

You'll need to change the Domain Controller policy setting as well:

> RDP - Allow log on through Terminal Services
>
> This security setting determines which users or groups have permission
>   to log on as a Terminal Services client. By default, on domain
>   controllers only Administrators have permission.

But you also shouldn't be allowing non-admins access to a domain controller...but you can determine your level of risk here...

Comment: This is just a test environment in a lab, not production.

Comment: Understood...should work once you go through the settings I listed.